# Dell Latitude D620, D/Port replicator, and Fedora 15

Tags: x-server, fedora-15, dell-latitude

I'm trying to get the Dell D/Port replicator's video switch to work correctly under Fedora 15 with a D620 laptop. I have the NVidia drivers from RPMFusion installed. Right now, nothing video-related works - the X Server sees the display connected to the replicator as a second display, even if the computer is booted in the replicator with the lid closed, and if I undock the computer, X acts as if the second display is still connected.

I did some research and it looks like some folks have had success with some kind of script that hooks an ACPI action, but I've had no luck with them on FC15...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I found a solution that kind of works.

In the nvidia x server settings, I set both displays to "Separate X Screen." I rebooted, and now it looks like Xfce will switch the taskbar and my panels between the external display and the laptop's display based on what is connected.

The problem with this solution is that it sees the laptop's LCD as a second monitor - so it's possible for the mouse pointer to get "lost" when it's really just hiding on the other display. :)